# Is there any way to make the .NET hot reload faster?

Tags: .net, blazor

I m working on a blazor project, whenever I use `dotnet run watch` and make any changes the project builds first and this takes so long ..

Is there any way to speed this up so that I can design my application faster?

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/q/68306900/6309? It was an interresting question, which could help others.

Comment: OK. I duplicate of which other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 6 Preview 3 introduced early [Hot Reload](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/#initial-net-hot-reload-support) feature that allows to change code and markup while application is running, this change is instant and you don't lose the application state.

While .NET 6 Preview is not production ready and hot reload isn't very stable, it can be effectively used to improve design productivity already.

### Install

1. Download preview .NET 6 SDK https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0
2. - Update all Microsoft.AspNetCore.* package references to 6.0.0-preview.3.*.
   - Update all Microsoft.Extensions.* package references to 6.0.0-preview.3.*.
3. Add `"hotReloadProfile": "blazorwasm"` to **launchSettings.json**
4. Set `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` in `.csproj`
5. Run `dotnet watch` as usual